# Responsive Mobile Menu Not Clickable

Tags: admin

When my website, https://liquidnicotinewholesalers.com , changes to have a responsive mobile menu, it is extremely hard to click using a tablet and a phone. I will continue to click the mobile menu on my iphone and it will open and close again so fast that the menu items are unable to be selected.

Please help!

Comment: Welcome to Magento SE. Debugging JS/CSS is a task that can
best be done on site and not a good question for the StackExchange Q&A. However, if you want
to try your luck, please provide as much
information as possible: Which theme are you using? Were there any modifications to the
theme? Did it work correctly before and if so, what has been changed (for example
installed extensions)? Do not just drop a URL - this can help to provide context but eventually you will fix your problem and the question remains without value for future visitors.

Comment: Thank you. We are using a customized RWD theme. We paid someone to customize it for us, but I'm not sure, how or when this started happening.